# error: GLSL 3.30 is not supported. Supported versions are: 1.10, 1.20, 1.30, 1.00 ES, 3.00 ES, 3.10 ES, and 3.20 ES

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, glsl

I have a Qt code for an 3D application developed with OpenGL. I'm trying to build/run the Qt application with QtCreator but I'm getting the following error:

```
Error in compiling shader.

0:1(10): error: GLSL 3.30 is not supported. Supported versions are: 1.10, 1.20, 1.30, 1.00 ES, 3.00 ES, 3.10 ES, and 3.20 ES
```

---

I tried adding the following to my code as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33482388/3405291):

```
QSurfaceFormat glFormat;
glFormat.setVersion(3, 3);
glFormat.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(glFormat);
```

Actually the above code worked, I mean the error got resolved. However, when application is running, it **doesn't show/render any 3D content**. For example when importing a STL file into the Qt application, the STL content is not shown. Did anybody run into a similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to help the next guy who might run into such an issue:

---

I built/ran the application on a computer belonging to a friend which has two graphic cards: one **Intel** and one **Nvidia**.

In the case of **Intel** graphics card the same previous issue occurred regarding OpenGL versions.

In the case of **Nvidia** graphics card, no OpenGL error happened. The application runs without any issue and the imported STL file could be rendered/viewed. Therefore my OpenGL error was **hardware-related**.

---

What I'm curious to know is how much effort would it take to modify the code so that the 3D application can run on **Intel** graphics card too. Who knows?

Comment: If it runs on NVIDIA but not on Intel then you probably rely on a not standard conform behaviour of NVIDIA in your code. NVIDIA e.g. has a default VertexArrayObject bound to location `0`, which is not standard conform and not using VAO correctly is the most common error why code code runs on NVIDIA but not on Intel or ATI.

Comment: @t.niese Thanks. I searched my project for the keyword `VertexArrayObject` but nothing is found. What other keyword might I search for to locate such an implementation?

Comment: I don't know the QT API that well. But somewhere in your code you created a Buffer holding the data you want to render and you should create a VAO using `glGenVertexArrays`. You then tell the opengl where in the data like position, color, ... are located using `glVertexAttribPointer` and `glEnableVertexAttribArray`,  before those functions you should have `glBindVertexArray`. So if `glBindVertexArray` or `glGenVertexArrays` are missing then you probably rely on  that Nvidia error.

Comment: @t.niese I just wonder if there is any good documentation which I can study to understand this topic. Thanks.

Comment: @t.niese Specifically, I found `glEnableVertexAttribArray` and `glVertexAttribPointer` in the code, but there is **no** `glBindVertexArray` and also there is **no** `glGenVertexArrays`

Comment: Either the [opengl specs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec44.core.pdf) or the [official OpenGL Wiki](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/). There are some tutorials like [learnopengl.com - Hello-Triangle](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Hello-Triangle) that seem to explain certain things quite well. But take care, all of the tutorials I know out there are either not well written or have errors. So you should always cross check with the offical wiki and specs. If you have further questions, please create a question with the explicit problem you have.

Comment: @t.niese Great. I'm going to study those materials. Thanks.